# Meaning of "saunter up" in football (soccer) context

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does "saunter up" mean in football (soccer) context?

FULL TIME! A consolation for Chelsea but Manchester City **saunter up** to fifth in the table, now just four points off the leaders Liverpool with a game in hand.

Comment: To saunter is to walk slowly in a casual manner. Presumably Man. City were moving up the league table quite slowly.

Comment: @KateBunting Thanks. By the way, what does "off" mean in this sentence? ...now just four points **off** the leaders Liverpool with a game in hand.

Comment: They  have four fewer points than Liverpool.